# Check if Image exists and if not bring in No Image file

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have this code to bring in the image of a property.

```vb
myDocument.Shapes("PropertyPic").Fill.Visible = msoTrue
myDocument.Shapes("PropertyPic").Fill.UserPicture PicLink & rs.Fields("PropertyName").Value & a & rs.Fields("PropertyId").Value & b
```

I need to add code to use the NoImage file if the pic doesn't exist.
I tried `On Error Goto Error handler`.

Answer (score 0):

One of several methods could be to try setting a reference to the shape and managing the error that way e.g.

```
Dim oShp As Shape
On Error Resume Next
Set oShp = myDocument.Shapes("PropertyPic")
If Err Then
  ' set no image
Else
  With oShp
    .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
    .Fill.UserPicture PicLink & _
    rs.Fields("PropertyName").Value & a & _ 
    rs.Fields("PropertyId").Value & b
  End With
End If
On Error Goto 0
```

Comment: Thank you Jamie. I'm trying this but running the code it's not detecting there is an error so kips to the Else part.

Comment: I have managed to figure out something. Will post completed code tomorrow. !

Comment: Dir$("c:\temp\nofile.jpg") will return a zero-length string if nofile.jpg doesn't exist in c:\temp.  Substitute the path/file name you're checking for, then use If Len(Dir$("c:\temp\nofile.jpg")) = 0 to test for a missing file.

Answer (score 0):

This is the final code I used

I ensured my variables I was using not duplicated and declared as global as I put this in another module..

```
Sub PropertyPic()

Dim oShp As Shape

 Set myDocument = ActivePresentation.Slides.Item(1)

'On Error Resume Next
Set oShp = myDocument.Shapes("PropertyPic")
On Error GoTo Err1:
  With oShp
    '.Fill.Visible = msoTrue
    .Fill.UserPicture linkproperty & _
     rs.Fields("PropertyName").Value & a & _
    rs.Fields("propertyID").Value & b
Exit Sub
Err1:
myDocument.Shapes("PropertyPic").Fill.UserPicture NoImage
'Exit Sub
'If Err.Number <> 0 Then

Resume Next
'Else
  End With
'End If
On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```